# Mostrar imágenes en React - No lo consigo hacer de forma eficiente

Tags: reactjs, imagen, img

Estoy trabajando con REACT. No consigo mostrar imágenes de una forma eficiente. La única forma que he encontrado de mostrar las imágenes es así:

Tengo un archivo **articulos.js** con los datos que quiero mostrar. En este archivo voy importando una a una las imágenes, pero esto no es factible, hay como 20 imágenes.

**articulos.js**

```
import abrigo1 from '../assets/images/abrigo1.jpg';
import camiseta1 from '../assets/images/camiseta1.jpg';
import abrigo1 from '../assets/images/abrigo1.jpg';


export const articulos = [
{
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Camiseta manga corta',
    'price': '30,99',
    'image': camiseta1
},
{
    'id': '2',
    'name': 'Abrigo',
    'price': '25,99',
    'image': abrigo1
},
{
    'id': '3',
    'name': 'Vestido largo flores rosa',
    'price': '25,99',
    'image': 'vestido1
}
}
```

**Articulo.js**  Este Componente es la vista dónde muestro las imágenes

```
import React from 'react';

export const Articulo = ({name, price, image, width}) => {

return (
    <div className="articulo" style={{width: width}}>
        

        <img src={image} alt={name} />
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{price}</p>
        <button>Añadir</button>
    </div>
)
}
```

Estructura de la App:

```
src
 |-----assets
          |-----images
                   |-----abrigo1.jpg
                   |-----vestido1.jpg
                   |-----camiseta1.jpg
          |-----components
                   |-----Articulo.js
          |-----data
                   |-----articulos.js
```

Lo he intentado hacer de otras cuantas formas y no hay manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguí resolverlo. Simplemente moví la carpeta **assets** (que contiene las imágenes) de la carpeta **src** a la carpeta **public**.
Luego no hace falta hacer ningún import de las imágenes.

El código queda tal que así.

**articulos.js**

```
export const articulos = [
{
    'id': '1',
    'name': 'Camiseta manga corta',
    'price': '30,99',
    'image': 'camiseta1'
},
{
    'id': '2',
    'name': 'Abrigo',
    'price': '25,99',
    'image': 'abrigo1'
},
{
    'id': '3',
    'name': 'Vestido largo flores rosa',
    'price': '25,99',
    'image': 'vestido1'
}
}
```

**Articulo.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export const Articulo = ({name, price, image, width}) => {

return (
    <div className="articulo" style={{width: width}}>
        

        <img src={`/assets/${image}.jpg`} alt={name} />
        <p>{name}</p>
        <p>{price}</p>
        <button class="btn-anadir">AÑADIR</button>
    </div>
)
}
```